# Review Said "Instagram profile permission(s) should not be used to authenticate new users in your app."

Tags: ios, authentication, instagram-api

Okay, So I have seen multiple issues(answered and unanswered) regarding Instagram API, haven't found anything related to my problem.

I have made an app in iOS which lets users download only profile pictures of any Instagram user in HD resolution.

After a long struggle, I have found all of the related API's And I am able to get the HD variant of Profile pictures in the app. Now the thing is those APIs read the phone's browser cookies that if I have authenticated the user in Instagram or not. And if I don't authenticate before the HD profile query id doesn't give me the desired data i.e no HD profile Url.

It means that I can only get the Instagram authentication before letting my users search and query for the HD profile pictures. So I figured out and added that using Instagram Basic Display API.

The problem came when I submitted the app for the Facebook developer review. They keep saying that **Instagram profile permission(s) should not be used to authenticate new users in your app.**

[image: Reviewers said]

And it's the 3rd time I told them that the app flow requires the authentication just to read cookies and I am not using any of the user's data for personal authentication, but they are not letting the app pass the review.

My need is can someone help me out if I am really using the wrong authentication process or maybe I am not able to convey my need to the reviewer. So what do I tell them, I am sure there is something going on wrong because I have seen some apps doing the same process in their apps.

Thanks for helping me out